# Website to IOS App

Tags: php, mysql, ios, sqlite, web

I have a website that I've created using PHP, Mysql, and other (HTML, CSS, etc) and I'm looking into converting the website into a native Iphone App for the app store. I know quite a bit of Objective-C and have used X-code for a couple years but I'm confused about one aspect of it. I've never worked with databases from an app. The database that we have set up is just a good old fashion PHP and Mysql that we connect to. It holds all of the site's users and other information.

Therefore, what should I do about accessing this database on the phone? Is there a way to use Mysql or is there something else that I can use that would interact with the database separately? I know there is SQLite but does that work with Mysql or not?

Any tutorials or guides you could point me to also would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Are you certain that it even makes sense to convert your web application to an iOS application? (Might it make more sense to produce a mobile version of the web site instead?) Anyways, we'll need at least some idea of what your site is doing to give you useful advice.

Comment: the site is musicaluniversity.com and it connects students and tutors on college campus so the database is used to store the profiles for the tutors.

Comment: Based on that description, I'd reiterate my recommendation that you build a mobile version of your site instead. You're unlikely to see any real advantage from having a native app, and a mobile site will be easier to put together (and will also work on non-iOS devices with no additional effort).

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is: **don't** connect an iOS app directly to the database. Think about it: you'd be embedding a username and password somewhere in the app's code, which some nefarious user *will* find a way to extract and exploit.

Much better way to do it: create a simple API on your website, then pass requests from mobile users through the API. Then your server handles all database connections, authentication of users, and so on, and you haven't put your database credentials in the hands of lots of unknown individuals.